# Ошибка при запуске проекта Yii2 и Yii2-Bootstrap

Tags: yii2, composer

При запуске проекта как говорят в видеокурсе, в том что `composer` пытается подключать каталог `C:\OSPanel\domains\site.open\vendor\bower`, хотя на самом деле он при установке пакета `C:\OSPanel\domains\site.open\vendor\bower-assset`

```
Invalid Argument – yii\base\InvalidArgumentException

The file or directory to be published does not exist: C:\OSPanel\domains\site.open\vendor\bower/bootstrap/dist
```

Одно из решений добавить настройки в `composer.json`, но у меня это не сработало.

```
"fxp-asset":{
    "installer-paths": {
    "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
    "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте в конфиге указать алиас `'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset'
    ]`

Comment: в секцию "fxp-asset" надо еще добавить `"enabled": false`